# Should I add something to prevent kickback on this LED circuit?

Tags: led

I am new to building circuits.  I am running the following LED circuit:

[image: Circuit diagram]

When I plug it in, there is an occasional "pop" of the LED.  Does the circuit need something like a diode to prevent a current kickback?  Or something else?

Comment: Are your LEDs rated to 1A?

Comment: The LEDs are CXA2520's,  According to the data sheet, the maximum DC forward current is 1.25A whereas the LDD provides a 1A constant current.

Comment: Are your LED's on any sort of heat sink?

Comment: Yes.  I use CPU heat sinks.  The temperature is at about 86F

Answer (score 2):

> **Should I add something to prevent kickback on this LED circuit?**

**No**.

There shouldn't be any "kickback" in that circuit.

---

The power supply looks like a [Mean Well S-350-27](http://www.meanwell.com/search/s-350/s-350-spec.pdf) which puts out 27V at up to 13A.

As Pete suggests in a comment, the cause of *'an occasional "pop" of the LED*' is likely to be that the [Mean Well LDD-1000H](http://www.meanwell.com/search/ldd-h/default.htm) constant-current LED driver (1000 mA output) exceeds the current rating of the LED module whose maker name and part number you are keeping a secret ;-)

As I understand it, a constant current driver like the LDD-1000H will increase Vout from 2 up to 52V until the current is approximately 1000 mA. If the LED module is rated 45V max ([for example](http://dx.com/p/diy-30w-6500k-2850-3000lm-white-light-round-cob-led-module-dc-36-45v-146066?tc=GBP&gclid=CKvf7LyKrboCFVMbtAodUSoApw)) but draws less than 1000mA, I would expect there will be a problem.

Comment: as noted on my comment to Pete - I am using CXA2520 LEDs.  The forward voltage has a typical value of 36V and max value of 42v.  As noted above, the DC forward current is 1.25 A max.  So doesn't it draw more than 1 A thus not fitting the scenario for problem?